# Is Volume by Revolution strictly for circular base shapes or could it be used for ellipses?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm attempting to find the volume of a vortex (excluding its spirals) with an elliptical base. I've tried using volume by revolution but was unable to go further. The properties of a and b for the ellipse are 2 and 3 respectively while the depth of the vortex is 4.
How do I proceed? And if Volume by Revolution doesn't work here, what do I do instead?

Comment: How do you define the vortex? Is it a [conical](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticCone.html), [parabolic](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticParaboloid.html), something else entirely?

Comment: @user170231 it is parabolic

Comment: In that case you need to provide a scaling parameter. How quickly do the sides of the parabola close in as one approaches its vertex? If the boundary curve is $y=kx^2$, then what's the value of $k$?

Answer (score 1):

Think about how the formula for the solid of revolution with a circular rotation is derived.

[image]

You have a disk of some thickness $\mathrm{d} x$, and base area $\pi r^2$, where $r=f(x)$. (We can assume that $\mathrm{d} x$ is so small, that the disk is in fact a perfect cylinder.) Hence, the disk contributes a volume $\mathrm{d} V$ to the solid, with

$$\mathrm{d} V = \pi r^2 \, \mathrm{d} x = \pi f(x)^2 \, \mathrm{d} x$$

If we are considering the solid of revolution between $x=a$ and $x=b$, then, to add up all of these, we integrate over $[a,b]$. (After all, that's arguably the point of integration: to add up incredibly many, incredibly small quantities, in a loose sense.) That is, the volume of the solid is given by

$$V = \int_{x=a}^{x=b} \mathrm{d}V = \pi \int_a^b f(x)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x$$

---

Consider how this process changes for an elliptical base. The entire process is almost the same, but now you want to deal with ellipses as your base, so you'll have

$$\mathrm{d} V = \text{(area of an ellipse)} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Figure that out and the answer should be immediate.

This notion generalizes quite well to rotations about other axes, or to solids with holes in them.

Comment: I've given it an attempt but does f(x)^2 remain as y? The axis on both sides are different and shrink. I can't seem to make it work

Comment: I apologize, I made an error within the math and overlooked the constant x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1